# Setting the font of SwiftUI's .searchable() with the appearance API of UITextField+UISearchBar doesn't work

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield, uisearchbar, searchable, uisearchbartextfield

I'm customizing the appearance of the `.searchable()` modifier of SwiftUI with the appearance API of `UISearchBar`.

Almost everything works, except the font of the text field, and I have no idea why (setting the font of the cancel button works, or setting the background color or text color of the text field also work, so the correct reference is there).

Talk is cheap, show me the code!

```
let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue,      // this works
    .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)   // this doesnt
]
let placeholder = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Search...",                         // this doesnt
    attributes: [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGray,    // this works
        .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15) // this doesnt
])

let textFieldAppearance = UITextField
            .appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
textFieldAppearance.backgroundColor = .red // this works
textFieldAppearance.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes // color works, font not
textFieldAppearance.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder // color works, font or text not
```

I guess it's time to file a -radar- feedback?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a reliable way of customizing this, with the solution posted below there's a glitch on the search bar that happens when SwiftUI re-renders the view (scrolling or just typing on the search bar), that is very obvious on a real device (not so much on the simulator).

**Old answer:**

Far from ideal, I found a way to make it work, which is introspecting the view searching for the `UITextField` and setting the font directly. The easiest way to do this is using a library like *SwiftUI-Introspect* (https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).

Then on the `View` you're using `.searchable()` from just:

```swift
.introspectTextField { textField in
    textField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
}
```

Fixed! The perfect solution would be to use the appearance API, but I guess we'll have to wait till iOS 16...

Comment: the `introspect` in my case can detect the `textField` but when I set any property on this `textField` it's not reflected, like the `textColor`, `font`, the `textField` appears with no changes at all

Comment: Same here. I can get a hold (aka a reference) to the search bar introspecting it, but trying to change the font does nothing

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `.font` and `.foregroundColor` modifiers after `.searchable` will do the desired result, but it still doesn't work with `.background` modifier (if you want it) as the time of this writing (iOS 16).

Comment: `.foregroundColor` doesn't work for me on iOS 16